# I need to make a change in a project and not have git acknowledge the change

Tags: git, visual-studio

I need to be able to make a change to a project and not have git ever send that change to the remote repository. I don't want the red checkboxes showing up in Visual Studio Solution Explorer indicating that something has changed, and I don't want the changes showing up as commits to be pushed to the server.

Is this possible?

The changes I need to make are connectionstrings that are different on different machines. As it is, I keep having to change them back every time I pull down commits. But then that change gets sent up and it starts all over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell git (wouldn't know how VS will behave) to not care for changes on a file with `git update-index --assume-unchanged`.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged some-file.txt
```

You can change the file and git won't care. This is a local operation, of course, no one else will know about it.

Comment: And I guess you should keep those settings on untracked files.... perhaps track sample files and ignore the real ones, if at all possible.

Comment: For the record, the red checkbox in VS disappears immediately after I enter that into the command line.

Comment: Apparently this makes permanent changes in how git tracks the file rather than just disregarding the existing changes. Good to know, but I can work with that.